# Laravel 5 Dependency Injecting a Repository into a controller, and depedency injecting an entity into repository

Tags: php, object-oriented, laravel, trait

Overview::

I have a Restful API that pushes all `/api/{version}/{Repository}` into my `ResourceV{1}Controller` depending on the `{version}` number. That `Controller` extends my Abstract Controller that has the majority of the controller logic, the ResourceV1Controller would load the V1 Interface for the API, and `ResourceV2Controller` would load V2 interface for the API etc.

I use a factory to load the correct API based on the `{Repository}` value to inject into my Controller.

I also inject the correct Entity into my Repositories when they are injected in my controller, so in the Repository I can reference `School::Where(....)->get()` as `$this->entity->where(...)->get()` instead.

This is two fold, I want to be able to write tests for each of these Repositories, and I want to use a Trait that moves duplicated code across all Repositories into one Location.

Here is what I have:

`Controller::`

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Api\Resource\v1\ResourceAPIInterface;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;


/**
* Class ResourceController
*/
class ResourceV1Controller extends RestController 
{

    /**
    * @param ResourceAPIInterface $api
    * @param Request $request
    * @param Router $router
    */
    public function __construct(ResourceAPIInterface $api, Request $request, Router $router)
    {
        $this->api = $api;
        parent::__construct($request, $router);
    }

}
```

`Parent Controller::`

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Api\Resource\v1\ResourceAPIInterface;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;


/**
 * Class RestController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers
 */
abstract class RestController extends Controller 
{

    /**
    * @var
    */
    public $api;


    /**
    * @param Request $request
    * @param Router $router
    */
    public function __construct(Request $request, Router $router)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }


    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index($version, $resource)
    {
        $input = $this->request->all();
        $data = $this->api->fetchAll($input);
        if(empty($data)){
             return (new Response(" ", 204))->header('Content-Type', 'application/json')->header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=3600');
       }else {
             return (new Response($data, 200))->header('Content-Type', 'application/json')->header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=3600');
       }
    }
 }
```

IoC Binding in Service Provider::

The $uri variable is exploded from the global REQUEST_URI variable

```
$this->app->bind('App\api\Resource\v2\ResourceAPIInterface',  function() use ($uri){
     $parts = explode('-', strtolower($uri[3]));
     $parts = array_map('ucfirst', $parts);
     $resource = implode('', $parts);
     $version = $uri[2];
     return Factory::getInstance($resource, $version);
});

$this->app->bind('App\api\Entity\v1\EntityInterface', function() use ($uri){
    $parts = explode('-', strtolower($uri[3]));
    $parts = array_map('ucfirst', $parts);
    $resource = implode('', $parts);

    $class = 'App\api\Entity\v1\\'.$resource;
    return new $class;
});
```

Factory::

```
<?php namespace App\api;

/**
 * API Factory creates the correct API/version to inject into controller
 *
 * @author  Dustin Parham <dr.parham@gmail.com>
 */
Class Factory
{

    const NS = "App\\api\\";

    /**
     *
     * @param string $api
     * @param int $version
     * @return APIInterface; 
     */
    public static function getInstance($api, $version='current')
    {
        if($version == 'current'){
            $apiConfig = \Config::get('api');
            //Check if API resource exists
            if(isset($apiConfig[$api])){
                $version = $apiConfig[$api]['currentVersion'];
            }else {
                //Need to throw 404 error
                \App::abort(404);
            }
            $version = $apiConfig[$api]['currentVersion'];
        }else {
            $apiConfig = \Config::get('api');
            $arr1 = str_split($version);
            //Check if API resource exists              
            if(isset($apiConfig[$api])){
                $arr2 = str_split($apiConfig[$api]['currentVersion']);
            }else {
                //Need to throw 404 error
                \App::abort(404);
            }

            if((int)$arr1[1]  >  (int)$arr2[1]){
                $version = $apiConfig[$api]['currentVersion'];
            }
        }

        $apiClass = self::NS.$api."\\".$version."\\".$api.'API';

        if (class_exists($apiClass)) {
            return \App::make($apiClass);
        }else {
            //Need to throw 404 error
            \App::abort(404);
        }
    }
 }
```

The config file api is an array of Repositories, and what their current version is.

Example Repository::

```
<?php namespace App\api\School\v1;

use App\api\Resource\v1\ResourceAPIInterface;
use App\api\Entity\v1\EntityInterface;

/**
 * Class SchoolAPI
 * @package App\api\School\v1
 */
class SchoolAPI implements ResourceAPIInterface
{

    const VERSION = '1';
    const NAME='School';
    public $entity;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function version()
    {
        return self::VERSION;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function name()
    {
        return self::NAME;
    }

    /**
     * @return EntityInterface
     */
    public function getEntity()
    {
        return $this->entity;
    }

    /**
     * @param EntityInterface $entityInterface
     */
    public function __construct(EntityInterface $entityInterface){
        $this->entity = $entityInterface;
    }

    /**
     * @param $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
     */
    public function fetchAll($data)
    {
         $data = $this->entity->all();
         return $data;
    }
...
```

Trait::

```
<?php namespace App\api\Traits\v1;

use App\api\Entity\v1\EntityInterface;


trait ApiUtilities {

    /**
     * @return EntityInterface
     */
    abstract public function getEntity();

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
     */
    public function deleteOne($id)
    {
        $data = $this->getEntity()->find($id);
        return $data->delete();
    }


    /**
     * @param $id
     * @param string $fieldName
     * @return bool
     */
    public function toggle($id, $fieldName='active')
    {
        $item = $this->getEntity()->find($id);
        $item->{$fieldName} = (int) !$item->{$fieldName};
        return $item->save();
    }
}
```

Overall, Is this the best way to accomplish this? I've seen different approaches to dealing with versioning a RESTful API, but wanted to cut down on duplicated code, and excess files.

Comment: You don't need to redefine your constructor in your `ResourceV1Controller`.

Comment: @BenHarold I actually had to remove the API injection from the RestController constructor, it was causing issues when trying to load a V2 Interface. Made edit to reflect changes.